why doesn't a TYPO3 command write data to the database?
I wrote a command to convert some data. To make it simple I use the repositories of the kind of records. For example the specific categories (tx_myext_domain_model_category) should be transferred to sys_category.
The reading works as I get a list of worked on records.
Then I transfer the data from $myext_category to $sys_category and add it to the repository:
$this->sysCategoryRepository->add($sysCategory);
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();

But in the database no records are generated.
My code for the category records:
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyExt\Command;

use MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category as SysCategory;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository as SysCategoryRepository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager;

use MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository as MyExtCategoryRepository;


class ConvertEventsCommand extends Command {

    /**
     * @var MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository
     * @Inject
     */
    protected $myExtCategoryRepository;
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository
     * @Inject
     */
    protected $sysCategoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
     * @Inject 
     */
    protected $persistenceManager;

    /**
     * @const int
     */
    protected $offsetCategories = 1000;
    protected $io;

    public function __construct(
        MyExtCategoryRepository $myExtCategorRepository,

        SysCategoryRepository   $sysCategoryRepository,
        PersistenceManager      $persistenceManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->MyExtCategoryRepository  = $myExtCategorRepository;
        $this->sysCategoryRepository    = $sysCategoryRepository;
        $this->persistenceManager       = $persistenceManager;

        // reading repositories:
        $querySettings = $this->myExtCategoryRepository->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
        $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
        $querySettings->setIgnoreEnableFields([]);
        $querySettings->setIncludeDeleted(false);
        
        $this->myExtCategoryRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);

        // writing repositories:
        $querySettings2 = $this->sysCategoryRepository->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
        $querySettings2->setStoragePageIds([123]);
        $this->sysCategoryRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings2);
    }

    /**
     * Configure the command by defining the name, options and arguments
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setDescription('converts data from ext:my_ext to sys_category')
            ->setHelp('gets all record from extension my_ext and convert it to records in sys_category ');
    }

    /**
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        Bootstrap::initializeBackendAuthentication();
        $this->io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
        $this->io->title($this->getDescription());

        $this->io->writeln('### copy categories ###');
        $this->copyCategories();
        $this->io->writeln('### done ###');
        
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * copy categories to sys_categories
     */
    public function copyCategories() {
        $myExtCategories = $this->myExtCategoryRepository->findAll();

        // create a new parent category
        $sysParentCategory = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category();
        $sysParentCategory->_setProperty('uid',$this->offsetCategories);
        $sysParentCategory->setPid(123);
        $sysParentCategory->setTitle('Event-Categories');

        $this->sysCategoryRepository->add($sysParentCategory);
        $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
        
        foreach ($myExtCategories as $myExtCategory) {
            $this->io->writeln('category '.$myExtCategory->getUid().': '.$myExtCategory->getName());

            $sysCategory = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category();

            $sysCategory->_setproperty('uid',$myExtCategory->getUid()+$this->offsetCategories);
            $sysCategory->setPid($myExtCategory->getPid());
            $sysCategory->_setProperty('hidden',$myExtCategory->_getProperty('hidden'));
            $sysCategory->_setProperty('starttime',$myExtCategory->_getProperty('starttime'));
            $sysCategory->_setProperty('endtime',$myExtCategory->_getProperty('endtime'));

            $sysCategory->setTitle($myExtCategory->getName());
            $sysCategory->setParent($sysParentCategory);

            $this->sysCategoryRepository->add($sysCategory);
            $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
        }
    }
}

What is missing?
what is wrong?

EDIT and more SPECIFICATION:
Without setting the uid the records are written, but with incrementing new uids. As I need the exact uids and not some random ones [1] as they should be referenced in other records and this would result in a lot of exchanging uids.
I tried to update the uid just after the record is written:
if ($doInsert) {
    $this->sysCategoryRepository->add($sysCategory);

    $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
    // now $syscategory should have the new uid
    $newUid = $sysCategory->getuid();
    $oldUid = $myExtCategory->getuid();
    if ($newUid != $oldUid) {
        // change uid $newUid to $oldUid of myExtCategory.....
        $updateSql = 'UPDATE sys_category SET uid = '.$oldUid.' WHERE uid = '. $newUid;
        //$this->io->writeln($updateSql.';');
        $q = $this->sysCategoryRepository->createQuery();
        $q->statement($updateSql);
        $queryResult = $q->execute();
        $this->persistenceManager->clearState();
    }
}

but no changes in the DB.
I also can not insert or update any fields regarding enableFields (hidden,deleted,starttime,endtime) which I also want to keep.
[1] as there are deleted records there are gaps even if I use ->setDefaultOrderings(['uid'=>QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING]); to get increasing uids for the findAll()

Not sure. But have you tried to not set the uid for new categories?

Does your BE user “_cli” have sufficient permissions?

@Mogens: As I have to convert 4 table with relations I need the uid so I can convert other records easily (use the same uid for the relations). Otherwise I need to build up a lot of relations explicit.

@JulianHofmann: yes. (switching to that user I can create any required records)

We had a similar case and could solve it by (re) initialization of the BE user via Bootstrap::initializeBackendAuthentication(). (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/CommandControllers/Index.html#initialize-backend-user)

that's the first line in function execute()

But did you try without setting the uid? Is this causing the problem? Maybe you can run a "raw SQL" later on to add the offset to the uids.

the problem is not so much about the offset but the records are not in order when I use fetchAll() (even with sorting there might be gaps)

@BerndWilkeπφ So it is working without setting a uid? What about adding a order by or custom fetch instead of fetchAll() so you could update the uid in a second run?

see my edit to my question: updating the uid doesn't work.

Did you try to update the uid not using the sysCategoryRepository?
For example like that?
// ... your code

$connectionPool = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
$q = $connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_category');
$connection = $connectionPool->getConnectionByName('Default');
$updateSql = 'UPDATE sys_category SET uid = '.$oldUid.' WHERE uid = '. $newUid;
$statement = $connection->executeQuery($updateSql);

// ... your code

